# self-signed SSL certificate error: certificate has invalid digital signature

Tags: windows-7, https, ssl-certificate, netsh

I have a c# program and part of it creates a self-signed certificate.

The problem is when i try to import the certificate in MMC it says "This certificate has an invalid digital signature."

And when i try to add this certificate through command prompt using netsh http add it says:

SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

I've tried all suggestions from other questions similar to this but to no luck.
I've also tried downloading Hotfix from Microsoft but it didnt work.

By the way, my machine is running in Windows7-64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an answer [here](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=41782) The basic issue is that DC authority cert creators get sloppy and create multiple certs for the same DC cert authority. I had my self-signed cert created using latest and grates DC cert authority certificate. I had to export and install both root cert and a self signed cert on my destination machine for it to recognize self signed cert used on the server. But the root cert I exported was a cert with the same name but different dates. Once I located the proper root cert and installed it on my destination computer everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to an old self signed certificate with a small key length.
I found the solution here - https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82606/26742 to reduce the security (only in my dev environment)

```
 certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512
```